# CSS start and pause animation on hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe, clip-path

I'm trying to get this [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxYPrN) to pause the animation and NOT snap back after completing while I am hovering over the `div`. I want the it to stay a square while I'm hovering over it.

I have searched around and have found  [this](https://codepen.io/MarkAlmond/pen/BHghr) kind of pause hover but is does not translate to my code.

```
/*HTML*/
 <div class="pers">
/*CSS*/
.pers{
 margin-bottom: -4px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: green;
 clip-path: polygon(50% 52%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.pers:hover{
 animation: polygons 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes polygons {
 75% 
{
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you are really close to it. Just need to add the keyframe for the `100%` state as well.

```css
.pers {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 52%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.pers:hover {
   animation: polygons 1s;  
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes polygons {
  75%,100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thisUs">
      <div class="pers">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the animation should be defined in the non-hover state. You should also define the `100%` step of the animation so you can keep it otherwise the initial polygon will be considered as the final step of the animation:

```css
.pers {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 52%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  animation: polygons 1s forwards paused;
}

.pers:hover {
   animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes polygons {
  75%,100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pers">
</div>
```

Comment: this sortof solved my problem. except i want it to go back to "normal" after you stop hovering.

Comment: @Satrat in this case you may consider transition : https://jsfiddle.net/4357avfu/1/